# How to add a transition to viewWillTransitionToSize

Tags: ios, core-animation, screen-rotation

I am developing in Objective-C for iPhone & iPad, currently at iOS11 and not using the Interface Builder.

I'm using viewWillTransitionToSize to handle my device rotations.

I want the UI that is presenting, as the rotation begins, to fade-out to black and, when the newly rotated UI is stable, I want the new UI to fade back in. Total fade-out/fade-in transition time to be about 1/2 second.

I've seen discussions that transitions can be integrated with viewWillTransitionToSize but I haven't seen examples and I am struggling with how to do what I want.

I've written the following code which makes the rotation transition a bit smoother. But it is still a long way from what I'd like to achieve:

```
- (void)  viewWillTransitionToSize: (CGSize) size
         withTransitionCoordinator: (id)     cord
   {
   [super viewWillTransitionToSize: size withTransitionCoordinator: cord];

   void (^midRotationBlk)(id) = ^(id cntx)
      {
      [gU updDevDirOrient: size];
      [self calcScrnCntAndScrollSize]; // recalculates horz scroll size
      [self updateViewConstraints];
      [[[self view] layer] addAnimation: [gU getTransitionEaseInOut: 0.5f]
                                 forKey: nil];
      };

   void (^endRotationBlk)(id) = ^(id cntx)
      {
      [self doScrollToPage: [self prevScrollPage]];
      };

   [cord animateAlongsideTransition: midRotationBlk
                         completion: endRotationBlk];
   }
```

The call to getTransitionEaseInOut looks like this:

```
- (CATransition *) getTransitionEaseInOut: (float) secs;
   {
   CATransition * transition = [CATransition animation];

   [transition       setDuration: secs];
   [transition setTimingFunction: [CAMediaTimingFunction
                functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
   [transition           setType: kCATransitionFade];

   return( transition );
   }
```

I've experimented with where I place the call to addAnimation within the viewWillTransitionToSize routine but none of the positions I've tried really helps.  I have the feeling I'm going about this all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked this out after a bit of experimentation.

In each of my view controllers, I have added an additional UIView.  It is sized to cover the entire physical screen.  It is always the last view added so it covers all the other detail below it. Its color is set to be the same color as the view controller's existing background color.  I refer to this over view as 'ovrView' in the code, below.

At entry, into the view controller, in viewWillAppear, I added the following code:

```
   ovrView.alpha = 1.0f;
   [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2f
                    animations: ^{ ovrView.alpha = 0.0f; }];
```

This has the effect to presenting the user with a blank background colored field each time I enter the view controller and this overlay vanishes after 0.2 seconds revealing the details below.

In each view controller's viewWillTransitionToSize routine, I added the following code:

```
- (void)  viewWillTransitionToSize: (CGSize) newSize
         withTransitionCoordinator: (id)     coordinator
   {
   //...this code executes before the rotation.

   [super  viewWillTransitionToSize: newSize 
          withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator];

   ovrView.alpha = 1.0f;

   void (^midRotationBlk)(id) = ^(id context)
      {
      //...this code executes during the rotation.

      [self updateViewConstraints];
      };

   void (^endRotationBlk)(id) = ^(id context)
      {
      //...this code executes after the rotation.

       [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4f
                       animations: ^{ ovrView.alpha = 0.0f; }];
     };

   [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition: midRotationBlk
                                completion: endRotationBlk];
   }
```

This code has the effect that the screen goes to a blank background color just before the rotation begins and then clears to reveal the post-rotation detail just after the rotation ends.

I tried fading-in the ovrView as the rotation began rather than just setting its alpha to 1.0f immediately.  But, I could always see the rotation beginning under the fading-in animation so I abandoned it.

None of this is necessary for the correct functioning of the App but it does create an effect I like as the user moves from one view controller to the next and as they rotate the device.